# Как в Википедии успевают за всем следить?

Tags: cms, движок

Давно уже интересует вопрос: как спроектирован Вики-движок, что успевают следить за ВСЕМИ статьями, и вовремя откатывать вандализм, спам и т.д.?

Comment: Просто очень много людей следит. Плюс видимо небольшая автоматизация.

Answer (score 7):

В вики движке есть страница "Свежие правки", где модераторы (которых там очень много) просматривают эти правки и отменяют их если это нужно. Примеры:

- Свежие правки;
- Служебная:RecentChanges;
- Свежие правки.

Answer (score 5):

Имеется странца свежих правок и страница новых статей.
Имеется специальное программное обеспечение для полуавтоматического просмотра свежих правок. Имеется система фильтров движка, система меток.
Имеются боты - специальные программы, которые выполняют автоматически некоторые действия. В частности, отслеживают повторные создания удалённых ранее статей.
Имеется спам-лист и глобальный спам-лист Фонда ВМФ.

Имеется 1 тысяча Патрулирующих (могут проставлять спец. отметку в статье о том, что в ней нет явного вандализма и спама), октатывающих (могут откатить сразу несколько правок нажатием одной кнопки), больше 50 Подводящих итоги (обладают правом удаления страниц), 190 администраторов (обладают правами удаления и защиты страниц, блокировок и тп).

Так же имеются списки наблюдения. У актвиных редакторов в них занесено несколько тысяч статей, и каждое утро (а некоторые и каждые 5 минут) они просматривают все правки, сделанные в интересующих их статьях.

Походите по служебным пространствам Википедии, изучите её внутреннюю кухню, и участвуйте в ограждении проекта от вандализма. Станьте редактором Википедии!